# Format ItemTemplate GridView money item to thousand seperator ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, currency

I have the Salary field in SQL Server table with money type, in the GridView ItemTemplate I use:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="Text">
    <HeaderTemplate>Basic Salary</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BasicSalary", "{0:0,0}")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

but it only display:6500000.0000  intead of my desired one is : 6,500,000. So how to do ? Please help!
If I use this fuction:

```
protected string Format_Number(string Number)
{
    Number = Number.Replace(".", "");
    Number = Number.Replace(",", "");
    var tmp = "";
    while (Number.Length > 3)
    {
        tmp = "." + Number.Substring(Number.Length - 3) + tmp;
        Number = Number.Substring(0, Number.Length - 3);
    }
    tmp = Number + tmp;
    return tmp;
}
```

then in the ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:label ID="lblSalary" 
               runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Format_Number(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Salary").ToString()) %>'>
    </asp:label>
```

the output is:
    6.500.000.000  I want to cutout the last 3 digit. How to do?

Comment: your formatting is correct i guess what's wrong is your Data binding is a string type. That's why your formatting is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway.. you convert it to decimal then reformat it should work

```
 protected string Format_Number(string Number)
 {
    // Variable
    string value = string.Empty;
    decimal castValue = 0;
    bool isValid = false;

    // Check
    if (Number != string.Empty)
    {
        // Parse
        isValid = decimal.TryParse(Number, out castValue);

        // Check & Set Decimal Valud
        if (isValid) value = castValue.ToString("0,0");
    }


    return value;
 }
```

Comment: I convert money type to decimal in SQL table and using this function. It works perfectly! Thanks! Both decimal or money type also work.

Comment: if you converted the type in SQL you don't need this function at all....
in your Eval there just need to format it as {0:0,0} should work

Comment: Use this function works but use Eval with {0:0,0} not works !<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BasicSalary", "{0:0,0}")%>

Comment: I tried i use this work. <%# string.Format( "{0:0,0}", Eval("Foo")) %>. Maybe you can have a try...Make sure your datatype return is "number" type

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a string, why not simply use a substring?

just like:

```
return tmp.Substring(0, tmp.Length - 4);
```

Comment: And what happens when the string is only 65?

Comment: If we use return tmp.Substring(tmp.Length - 4); The output is 000

Comment: @Mathemats you should check that first, that's true.

Comment: @user3035133 yeah, I made a mistake, I've corrected it :)

Comment: C'mon Stefan, don't change your answer and then tell me I'm wrong.

Comment: @Mathemats I didn't say you're wrong, what you said is absolutely correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this

```
salary = salary.Replace(".", "");
salary = salary.Replace(",", "");
string tmp = (Convert.ToInt64(salary)).ToString("N", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use any function "Format_Number(string Number)". Directly bind as money data type. This is work for me.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Basic Salary">
                <HeaderTemplate>Basic Salary</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BasicSalary", {0:0}")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```